# Java String [] return

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I'm stuck on a problem with returning a whole `String[]`:

```
ArrayList<File> Files = (ArrayList<File>) data.getSerializableExtra(FILES_TO_UPLOAD); //file array list
String [] files_paths = new String[5]; //string array
int i = 0;
for(File file : Files){
  //String fileName = file.getName();
  String uri = file.getAbsolutePath();
  files_paths[i] = uri.toString(); //storing the selected file's paths to string array files_paths
  i++;
}
return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files_paths[0]);
```

Problem is I need to return all files paths but really don't know how.
In this case I return only `[0]`.
`return` can not be in `for()`. How should I do it?

Whole method

```
  private Bitmap decodeSingleBitmapFromIntent(Intent data) {
ArrayList<File> Files = (ArrayList<File>) data.getSerializableExtra(FILES_TO_UPLOAD); //file array list
            String [] files_paths = new String[5]; //string array

            int i = 0;

            for(File file : Files){
                //String fileName = file.getName();
                String uri = file.getAbsolutePath();
                files_paths[i] = uri.toString(); //storing the selected file's paths to string array files_paths

                i++;
            }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files_paths);
    }

    private void displayImage(ImageView image, Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap output = returnOriginalOrScaleIfToBig(bitmap);
        image.setImageBitmap(output);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you return the `files_paths` variable because that's what you want to do?

Comment: I tried
`Error:(325, 41) error: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String`

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to return a `String[]`, it's returning a `Bitmap`. How have you tried returning the array?

Comment: Now its `private String[]` and return `files_paths;`
Application crashed when it goes to return with
`Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

method signature changes from `Bitmap` -> `Bitmap[]` (bitmap array)

```
//notice the change in the signature
private Bitmap[] decodeSingleBitmapFromIntent(Intent data) {
        ArrayList<File> Files = (ArrayList<File>) data.getSerializableExtra(FILES_TO_UPLOAD); //file array list
        String [] files_paths = new String[5]; //string array

        Bitmap[] bitmapArray = new Bitmap[5];

        int i = 0;

        for(File file : Files){
            //String fileName = file.getName();
            String uri = file.getAbsolutePath();
            files_paths[i] = uri.toString(); //storing the selected file's paths to string array files_paths

            // decode each individual file, save reference in array
            bitmapArray[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files_paths[i]);

            i++;
        }

        //return the complete array
        return bitmapArray;
    }
```

---

You must change the Return type of the method you are using and return a `Bitmap[]`

ie

if your method is declared like this:

```
public Bitmap getImage(){...}
```

it could be declared to return a bitmap array instead:

```
public Bitmap[] getImages(){...}
```

now you will be able to return all the bitmaps which in your `Bitmap[]` (Bitmap Array) composed of multiple `Bitmap`s

The error you are getting is caused by the method's signature not matching the return type, you need to return the complete array if I understood correctly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I pasted whole method, what about `Bitmap`, not `String`?

Comment: Stil nothing
`Error:(324, 16) error: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to Bitmap[]`
`Error:(349, 54) error: incompatible types: Bitmap[] cannot be converted to Bitmap`

Comment: `Error:(347, 54) error: incompatible types: Bitmap[] cannot be converted to Bitmap`

Comment: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to Bitmap[]

means that somewhere you are  trying to save this new  result in your old variable which was ready to save a string array

'Bitmap[] cannot be converted to Bitmap'
means that you are also trying to save the result of this method which is Bitmap[] bitmapArray

Comment: 'Bitmap[] cannot be converted to Bitmap'
means that you are also trying to save the result of this method which is Bitmap[] bitmapArray inside a variable that is of type Bitmap

Comment: @RafałSzymiczek have you been able to solve your problem? I believe this answer should be marked as the correct one, let me know if this helped =)

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that you need to return the all the file paths, you need to use:
`return files_paths;`
**Not:**
`return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files_paths[0]);`
or
`return files_paths[0];`// or any other index other than 0

Your function also needs to have a return type of `String[]`.
You might also want to use the class ArrayList since it will provide you an ease to perform other operations on your data.

Also, I noticed that you named the very first variable in the code with an upper case. That is the convention used to declare a class and should not be used for variables. For variables you must keep the first letter lower case.

Answer (score 0):

The question you posted is not coherent with the code you write....

you say you are returning a path at index 0 but in the code I see

```
return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files_paths[0]);
```

which means you are returning a `Bitmap` from the filePath at index 0

totally different things...

if you want need to return all the paths then change the return tyoe of the  method to

```
String[]
```

and `return files_paths;` instead of the Bitmap